# Is there a way to report dashboard, funnel or breakdown from Facebook as email?

Tags: facebook-analytics

I want system to send me monthly reports of analytics reports. How can i create such a system that sends monthly reports automatically as a mail?

If this is not possible, then how can i save custom dashboard as pdf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not support downloading dashboards as PDFs. There couple of alternate options:
1) Some of the reports support "Download as CSV" option (see image below).
2) We send key metrics via. our emails.

[image]